# Android Studio no muestra estructura de proyecto

Tags: android-studio, git, bitbucket

He subido a bitbucket mi proyecto en Android Studio que está en otro PC (Mac) y aquí mi problema:. 
Estoy descargándolo de bitbucket a Android Sstudio en otro PC (Windows) y me descarga los archivos pero no me muestra la estructura del proyecto.

[image: Me muestra esto]

Comment: revisa si están versionados tus archivos .gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Asegura que los archivos `settings.gradle` y `build.gradle` estan versionados para que identifique tu proyecto, ya que estos son los que configuran el proyecto.**

Da click en donde dice **Android** y selecciona algun tipo de despliegue, generalmente se usa `Project` o `Android`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer no tenia bien configurado los archivos settings.gradle y build.gradle, ya lo he solucionado muchas gracias.

Comment: Que bien, Darce, anteriormente usando eclipse los archivos que configuraban el projecto eran .classpath .properties, ahora en Android Studio son settings.gradle y build.gradle. Si vas a cargar un proyecto que no este creado en Android Studio puedes Importar, con eso automáticamente crea tus archivos .gradle, saludos.